# How to check in If-Statement if a screen is already running

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I want to write a bash script where I check If my Screen (I gave this screen the name `a3_altis`) is already running or not, just like this:

```
if (screen a3_altis is running)
  then
    ./stop.sh
    sleep 5
    ./start.sh
  else
    ./start.sh
fi
```

I'm new in Bash, so I don't really know how to check If a screen is running.

Comment: You should be more precise about "screen running". Is it an X server? Local, remote? Do you refer to the variable $DISPLAY?

Comment: It's a local screen on my server. And I do not refer to the $DISPLAY variable.

Comment: Are looking for an instance of the terminal emulator `screen`, or are you asking about something else entirely?

Comment: I'm looking for an instance of the terminal emulator `screen`

Comment: In either case, you should not expect the command `[a3_altis` to exist.  You need space after `[` to separate it from its first argument.  `ls foo` lists the names in `foo`.  `lsfoo` is not a command.  Similarly, `[ a3_altis` will invoke `[` with one argument, but `[a3_altis` is not likely to be in your PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screen` may provide a more robust mechanism, but it should suffice to just use `grep`:

```
if screen -ls | grep -q a3_altis; then
    ./stop.sh
    sleep 5
fi
./start.sh
```